# set kafka retention policy globally (not per topic)

Tags: apache-kafka

- What I am trying to achieve:

I would like to apply a retention policy to Kafka globally, and not per topic.

I have a test Kafka cluster, in which there are thousands of test topics.
The topics hold test messages, for an asserter to consume.

I which to configure this for all topics: "The messages should only stay in the topic for an hour max, for all topics."

- What did I try:

So far, I am setting the retention on a per-topic basis. Meaning, that when I create the topic, I manually configure each topics (thousands of them) setting up the expiration after an hour.

- Issue:

As we have more than thousands of topics, this task of setting the expiration per topic is quite hard to manage. Is there a way to configure Kafka once, so that by default, all messages expire after an hour, for all topics?

Comment: Messages don't have individual TTLs. Retention settings affect log segments (groups of messages) instead. In other words, you'll end up having data longer than an hour in most cases

Answer (score 0):

You can be setting up that on Kafka Brocker properties level using next properties:

### log.retention.hours

The number of hours to keep a log file before deleting it (in hours), tertiary to log.retention.ms property

##### Type:  int

##### Default:   168(7 days approx)

---

### log.retention.minutes

The number of minutes to keep a log file before deleting it (in minutes), secondary to log.retention.ms property. If not set, the value in log.retention.hours is used